# Trigger when `SelectedIndex` greater than 0

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, selection, mutual-exclusion

How can I set a trigger on a `ComboBox` that when the `SelectedIndex` is greater than 0 (basically, when an option is selected) another `ComboBox` gets modified. What I have are two `ComboBox`es but the user can only select from one of them. So if I select the first option from `ComboBox` A then `ComboBox` B should get a `SelectedIndex` of 0 , and vice versa.

I've tried toying with the following but not sure how to capture the logic required.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableStatuses}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStatus}"
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          x:Name="Statuses">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Decisions}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

What sort of trigger should I be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be much simpler to just have this logic in the ViewModel, wherever your "SelectedStatus" property is. If the value coming in is greater than 0, set the other property ("SelectedStatus2"?) to 0 and vice versa.

Comment: I agree with Ben K. Doing this in XAML only will be very tricky if even possible. Either code the logic into a VM or use code behind in the view. 

Alternative would be to write a user control with an items control with combo boxes as items. The user control would then have code to enforce only one combo box is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just bind the `SelectedIndex` property of `ComboBox` B to the `SelectedIndex` property of `ComboBox` A?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a converter that returns True/False if the SelectedIndex is greater than 0

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Decisions, 
    Converter={StaticResource IsValueGreaterThanZeroConverter}}" Value="True">
```